# hyperledger fabric 1.0 alpha2,Timeout expired while starting chaincode

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I deploy a demo as document of http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

When the cli node execute instantiateChaincode function in `script.sh`,throws an Error:

> Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = 2 desc = Timeout expired while starting chaincode mycc:1.0(networkid:dev,peerid:peer0.org1.example.com,tx:36950e4638442cdd37215838c2bd6062af63b6f0e729b43d76eda0f3e1eb6b8b)

I could not remove this error so long time.

How did I do it?

Comment: Answer by Nick G helped. However, in my case, it worked without RESTARTing docker engine.

Answer (score 0):

It happens the same errors to me. Because I set wrong network in docker compose file. The peers and orderer are not at same networks, they can't communicate with each other.

Please check if you set this while starting the network using `docker-compose`: `CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_byfn`
and **related networks** in your docker file.

For example,

if you config your docker file like this:

`peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.org1.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn`

you need to set `CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE`, and the prefix of the value is your directory's name, the suffix of the value is your networks's value(i.e. byfn), and use "_" to connect the prefix and suffix.

You can follow [this url](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) to set the network in docker compose.

Make sure the peer and orderer on the same network.

Answer (score -1):

This is a tough one to diagnose with that amount of information.  Some helpful tips to remedy though... make sure you have the most up to date fabric images and utilities - no need to build from source, just follow the instructions outlined in the prerequisites section.  Check your versioning for Go, Docker, etc...  Kill any stale containers and prune your persisted docker networks.    `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)` & `docker network prune`.

Now RESTART your docker engine.  Ironically this actually solves connectivity errors more often than one would think.  Now proceed by following the "Build Your First Network" tutorial.  http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html